# Relationship: belongsTo this model or a different model

Tags: laravel, laravel-5

We have the following

```
Manager
[id]

Companies
[id]
[manager_id] not nullable

Stores
[id]
[company_id]
[manager_id] *nullable*
```

I am looking for a single Eloquent relationship for the manager of *every* store.

Any suggestions?

Answer (score 1):

Building on your comment @Sanjay S

```php
class Store extends Model {

public function manager() {
    return $this->belongsTo('App\Manager');
}

public function getManager() {
    if (is_null($this->manager)) {
        return $this->company()->manager;
    } else {
       return $this->manager;
}
```

Then when you call $store->getManager() you will get the company manager if store manager_id is null

Comment: yes but will that work link a relationship? I'm looking to do something like `$store->manager->name`

Comment: You could do $store->getManager()->name.
getManager() just gives you the manager object (from the store if not null, from the company if null), you can use whatever properties there exist.

Answer (score 0):

You question is not clear as your relationship in the **stores** table is like **manager_id [nullable]** and you are asking for **a single Eloquent relationship for the manager of every store.** But from my guesses your Eloquent models should be look like this

```
class Manager extends Model {

    public function stores() {
        return $this->hasMany(App\Store::class);
    }

    public function company() {
        return $this->hasOne(App\Company::class);
    }
}
```

**Company** class

```
class Company extends Model {

    public function manager() {
        return $this->belongsTo(App\Manager::class);
    }
}
```

**Store** class

```
class Store extends Model {

    public function manager() {
        return $this->belongsTo(App\Manager::class);
    }
}
```

Hope this solution works for you.

Comment: `Store` also has a `company()` relationship. I am looking to extend the `manager()` relationship of `Store` to return either the `Store` `manager` or if that is `null`, then return the `Company` `manager`